# Two ClickOnce Windows applications on the same server

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I have an issue installing two ClickOnce Windows applications on the same server. I have published one successfully. I have a requirement to install this same application on a different website in [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services). This is a copy of the existing application with slightly different functionality (not important). After I publish and try to install it, I get the following error:

> Unable to install this application because an application with the
>   same identity is already installed. To install this application,
>   either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall
>   the preexisting application.

I've tried changing the assemblyIdentity version number and name in the *Properties* -> app.Manifest, tried changing the *Assembly name* in the Project properties, tried clearing the manifest cache and none of these worked. I realize that this is the same application that I'm trying to install on two different websites on the same server, but what needs to be changed so that it will install correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Product Name of your application's deployment.  This is the application name stored in the deployment manifest file. Making this name different between your 2 instances will allow you to install both of them at once.   If setting this through Visual Studio, this is under the Options button on the Publish tab of your project's properties window.